# Capturar datos char con gets en C

Tags: c

intento hacer un pequeño ejercicio pero tengo un error que no comprendo.

```
int main(){
int n;
printf("Ingrese el numero de nombres: ");scanf("%i",&n);
char nombres[n];
for (i=0;i<n;i++){
printf("\nIngrese la primera palabra: ");gets(nombres[i]);
}
}
```

al compilar, el primer printf me muestra dos veces Ingrese la primera palabra y no entiendo que tengo mal, o si se puede usar gets de esa manera, alguien podria ayudarme a conocer mi error?

Answer (score 1):

> > Capturar datos char con gets en C

Analicemos paso a paso esta parte del código:

```
printf("Ingrese el numero de nombres: ");
scanf("%i",&n);
char nombres[n];
for (i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    printf("\nIngrese la primera palabra: ");
    gets(nombres[i]);
}
```

Este código lo que hace es pedir la cantidad de elementos que tendrá mi arreglo, posteriormente se ejecutará el bucle para pedir un `string` al usuario, el problema es que la función no se detendrá a la espera de un dato y esto se debe porqué anteriormente habíamos llamado a la función `scanf` para leer un número entero y esto hace que el búfer del teclado se quede sucio, es decir, internamente estará el salto de línea en el búfer (`\n`) y esto ocasiona que la función `gets` no se pause porqué esta subrutina deja de leer caracteres hasta que encuentre el salto de línea en el búfer; sin embargo, en la primera llamada de esta función, ocurrirá un fallo de segmentación, debido a que, se le está pasando al parámetro de la función `gets` el contenido de X posición del arreglo y nosotros no sabemos si ese **CONTENIDO** coincide con una dirección de memoria que al programa no le pertenece y esto hará que la función `gets` intente escribir algún caracter en esa dirección y esto hace que ocurra un fallo de segmentación (este error pasa cuando se intenta acceder a una dirección de memoria que el programa no tiene acceso).

Ahora, para poder lograr que el programa se pause al momento de pedir una palabra al usuario, debemos limpiar el búfer del teclado.

```
int main(void)
{
    int n, i, ch;
    printf("Ingrese el numero de nombres: ");
    scanf("%i",&n);
    char nombres[n];
    //Esto limpia el búfer del teclado
    while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("\nIngrese la primera palabra: ");
        gets(nombres[i]);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Sin embargo, el código seguirá teniendo la falla de segmentación, por esa razón, necesitamos pasarle al parámetro de la función `gets`, la dirección de memoria del primer elemento del arreglo, por lo tanto, es innecesario crear un bucle para pedir una palabra al usuario cuando podemos hacer esto:

```
int main(void)
{
    int n, i, ch;
    printf("Ingrese el numero de nombres: ");
    scanf("%i",&n);
    char nombres[n];
     //Esto limpia el búfer del teclado
    while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
    printf("\nIngrese la primera palabra: ");
    //Le enviamos al parámetro de la función gets la dirección base (el del primer elemento) del arreglo NOMBRES.
    gets(nombres);
    //Esto me debería imprimir el nombre
    printf("%s\n", nombres);
    return 0;
}
```

De este modo, no habrá ningún fallo de segmentación, debido a que, la función `gets` estará escribiendo caracteres en direcciones de memoria que si le pertenecen al programa.

También te daré algunas observaciones:

**1.** El identificador que le has puesto al arreglo, debería estar en singular, no en plural y esto se debe porqué no estás almacenando múltiples de nombres, sino, un único nombre.

Es decir, este identificador:

```
char nombres[n];
```

Debería ser cambiado por esto:

```
char nombre[n];
```

**2.** La función `gets` no es recomendable para pedir cadenas por teclado, debido a que, esta función no sabe cual es el tamaño máximo del arreglo. Por ejemplo, si la longitud máxima de `nombres` fuera `5` y luego el usuario escribe `Hola Mundo`, la función `gets` mandará los caracteres de `Hola Mundo` al arreglo `nombres`, pero el problema es que el arreglo solo admite hasta 5 caracteres y aquí es donde ocurrirá el famoso desbordamiento de búfer, este tipo de error te puede ocasionar muchos problemas, en algunos casos tu programa podría dejar de funcionar si se intenta sobreescribir en algún espacio ocupado por el sistema o incluso se podría escribir en bloques de memoria pertenecientes al mismo programa y esto haría que el problema sea más complicado de solucionar. Así que por seguridad no se debería de usar esta función.

Una solución sería usar la función [fgets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/), esta subrutina si te deja especificar el tamaño del arreglo y no ocasionaría ningún desbordamiento porqué solo leerá caracteres hasta la cantidad máxima que le especifiquemos.

```
int main(void)
{
    int n, i, ch;
    printf("Ingrese el numero de nombres: ");
    scanf("%i",&n);
    char nombres[n];
    while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
    printf("\nIngrese la primera palabra: ");
    fgets(nombres, n, stdin);
    return 0;
}
```

También debemos tomar en cuenta, que la función [fgets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) te incluirá el salto de línea en el arreglo, siempre y cuando, la cantidad de caracteres leídos por [fgets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/), sean menor al tamaño máximo del arreglo.

Por ejemplo, si `n` vale `6` y el usuario escribe `Hol`, `fgets` en este caso incluirá el `\n` en el arreglo porqué `3` < `6` (en este caso son 3, porqué lo que introduzco el usuario fue un `Hol`), por lo tanto, tu arreglo en memoria quedaría así:

```
Hol\n\0
```

Ahora, tu decidirás si quieres eliminar el salto de línea o no, porqué si quieres imprimir algo en una línea, no saldrá de la manera que esperas.

Ejemplo:

```
int main(void)
{
    printf("\nIngrese la primera palabra: ");
    fgets(nombres, 24, stdin);
    printf("Nombre: %s\n", nombres);
    return 0;
}
```

El resultado por pantalla será (obviamente, aplicando el ejemplo de arriba):

```
Nombres:
Hol
```

La palabra `Hol` sale en la siguiente línea porqué la cadena tiene el salto de línea, si no quieres que pase esto, debes eliminarlo de esta forma:

```
int main(void)
{
    int len;
    printf("\nIngrese la primera palabra: ");
    fgets(nombres, 24, stdin);
    //Obtenemos la longitud
    len = strlen(nombres);
    //Si el último caracter es un salto de línea
    if(nombres[len - 1] == '\n')
        //Reemplazamos un caracter nulo por el salto de línea
        nombres[len - 1] = '\0';
    printf("Nombre: %s\n", nombres);
    return 0;
}
```

Y de este modo, se imprimirá todo en una sola línea.

**3.** Los [VLA](https://www.reidatcheson.com/c/programming/2015/12/07/vlas.html) (Variable Length Arrays) son peligrosos, debido a que, no se puede detectar el error si es que llegara a suceder un desbordamiento de pila. Una buena opción es usar la función [malloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/), esta subrutina es más seguro, porqué podemos detectar si hubo una falla de asignación y avisarle al usuario del error. También recalco, que los arreglos con longitud variable, fueron introducidos a partir de C99 y por lo tanto es algo [estándar](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) (**6.7.5.2 Array
declarators**), sin embargo, muchos compiladores no lo soportan por la misma razón que mencioné anteriormente (es inseguro).

Tu código quedaría así con los cambios hechos:

```
int main(void)
{
    int n, i, ch;
    char* nombre;
    printf("Ingrese la longitud del nombre: ");
    scanf("%i",&n);
    //Reservamos memoria de forma dinámica
    nombre = malloc(n);
    //Si hubo un error al asignar memoria dinamica
    if(nombre == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error de asignacion");
        return 1;
    }
    while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
    printf("\nIngrese una palabra: ");
    fgets(nombre, n, stdin);
    //Hay que liberar la memoria
    free(nombre);
    return 0;
}
```